# How to automatically logout user from Guacamole after date expiration?

Tags: php, angular, curl, tomcat, guacamole

I developped an application in php to interagit with my guacamol with curl, in order to configure the date of acess and expiration.
I succeded ! But I noticed that once the date expired, the user remains logged in ...

I thought of 2 solutions :
Maybe I forgot a setting to automatically log out users with an expired date.
Or I want request to know the token of users connected and kick him with other request.
DELETE http://server/guacamole/api/session/"token"

I have try to delete token of users and it work but I don't know how I can get token of user with a request.

I'm Greatful for any help